# twitter OAuth error

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

When I run the example on (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter) page, I get the following error. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a7d2f82e2d8f> in <module>()
      1 t = Twitter(
----> 2             auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
      3                        CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

NameError: name 'OAUTH_TOKEN' is not defined
```

Comment: just a wild guess, but have you defined `OAUTH_TOKEN` and the rest of the constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original tutorial actually has this

```
# see "Authentication" section below for tokens and keys
t = Twitter(
        auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
                   CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
       )
```

You should take the comment's advice and read the authentication section of the documentation. The OAuth section should explain how to define the constants that are undefined in your OAuth() call.